# How can I find out servers my Android box is connecting to?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have an Android TV box and want to know which IP addresses it is connecting to view the network traffic. How can I do this?

My router (Netgear Nighthawk R7000) does not have a feature like many others which allows me to view specific network traffic.

Do I need to create a Man In the Middle to monitor it? Any other easier way?

Comment: May be a bit overkill for simply monitoring IP address connections, but [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) is one option.

Answer (score 1):

This router fully supports third party firmware.

Unfortunately it doesn't come with SNMP on the stock firmware. It is fully capable of running dd-wrt, and a couple other flavors of firmware.

Look into upgrading the firmware. You will get alot more bang for your buck with this router. (Many many more features than stock.) Get some SNMP monitoring action going.

https://www.tweaking4all.com/hardware/netgear-r7000-dd-wrt/

Regards,